# Resetting a queue discipline back to the default pfifo_fast one?

Tags: linux, tc

I'm trying to temporarily set a rate-limited queue discipline and then remove it a bit later:

```
# /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth1 root tbf rate 600kbit latency 50ms burst 1540
# /sbin/tc qdisc del dev eth1 root
```

Unfortunately, this entirely removes the queue discipline and prevents outgoing data transfers from working after the queue is deleted.

I was hoping to be able to reset the queue discipline back to the default one:

```
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: dev eth1 root refcnt 2 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

However it doesn't look like that [pfifo_fast](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/classless-qdiscs.html#qs-pfifo_fast) qdisc can be created manually:

```
# /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth1 root pfifo_fast
qdisc 'pfifo_fast' does not support option parsing
```

The work-around I found is to create a new simple queue discipline:

```
# /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth1 root prio
```

However, I was wondering how to reset this back to the real [default](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.classless.html) without rebooting.

Answer (score 13):

to remove and add a new queue discipline:

```
tc qdisc del dev eth1 root
tc qdisc add dev eth1 root pfifo
```

or if a queue discipline is already in place you can replace it directly:

```
tc qdisc replace dev eth1 root pfifo
```

Comment: This doesn't reset to pfifo_fast, only pfifo, which is different. OP's comment about what happens if you try to do this with '_fast' is relevant.

Answer (score 5):

from [http://www.knowplace.org/pages/howtos/traffic_shaping_with_linux/examples.php](https://web.archive.org/web/20150221210048/http://www.knowplace.org/pages/howtos/traffic_shaping_with_linux/examples.php):

```
tc qdisc del dev eth1 root
```

Comment: As I stated in the question, that's what the documentation lead me to believe, but it doesn't work on Debian/Ubuntu since it removes the queue entirely without adding back the default one.

Comment: it works for me on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Works for mee-too on Ubuntu Vivid. After deleting the qdisc, it returns to the default pfifo_fast.

Answer (score 2):

The man page for pfifo_fast (man tc-pfifo_fast) says that interfaces automatically have the pfifo_fast qdisc attached - when you then add a different qdisc and then delete this qdisc, pfifo_fast will automatically go back into service.

This suggests something has broken in the OP's setup.

Tested with:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian-testing-vm 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```